# Having problems with list and find Python

Tags: python, list

I was scripting a Discord bot with Python and wanted to make like a System that sends you a code and you have to re-send it. I made it so that the Username and the Code was stored in a list. Now I want to find the Value with:

```
result = [x for x in PW if x.startswith(str(member))]
```

and it printing out: ['DivScripts#7769PASSWORD'].
Everything fine until there. When I want to check now if the User has wrote the code in his message with this code:

```
if result in msg.content:
```

An error appears:

```
if result in msg.content:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Can `result` be empty or contain more than one element? If not, `if result[0] in msg.content`. If it's empty, there's nothing to check, and if it could contain multiple entries, you have to decide which (if not each) entry should be checked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a list containing a value; if you know you'll only get one value back

- optionally make sure you only have one

  ```py
  if len(result) != 1:
      raise ValueError("expected exactly one value in result")
  ```
- get that value out of the list by-index `result[0]`

to illustrate the difference

```py
>>> result = ["foo"]
>>> result     # a list containing a string
['foo']
>>> result[0]  # just a string
'foo'
```